Restricting Node.js only to a subdirectory on a Plesk server
I have successfully set up Node.js on my Plesk server following these instructions. However, when activated on the domain, it messes up my existing website, displaying a default node.js page. I would like it to only be active in a specific directory on the server, and leave the rest of the server (Document Root: /httpdocs) handled by PHP only. Is that possible and if so, how to set it up accordingly?
